# sslv3 alert certificate unknown

Tags: docker, ssl, redis, openssl, sslv3

I m trying to make a ssl/tls enabled redis application using a docker container.
i have added the redis.conf file and added the certificates to the redis container but i m getting this log every time my application try to connect to the give port.

`# Error accepting a client connection: error:0A000416:SSL routines::sslv3 alert certificate unknown (addr=172.17.0.1:65440 laddr=172.17.0.2:6380)`

here is the conf file for the same

```
# Enable TLS

port 0
tls-port 6380
tls-cert-file /usr/local/etc/redis/ssl/server-cert.pem
tls-key-file /usr/local/etc/redis/ssl/server-key.pem
tls-client-cert-file /usr/local/etc/redis/ssl/client-cert.pem
tls-client-key-file /usr/local/etc/redis/ssl/client-key.pem

# Specify the CA certificate file or directory
tls-ca-cert-file /usr/local/etc/redis/ssl/ca-cert.pem
```

alternatively I tried making client auth off using

```
tls-auth-clients no
```

I made sure path for the certificates is correct

#### docker logs for further debug

```
2023-11-22 16:08:42 1:C 22 Nov 2023 10:38:42.248 * oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
2023-11-22 16:08:42 1:C 22 Nov 2023 10:38:42.248 * Redis version=7.2.3, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
2023-11-22 16:08:42 1:C 22 Nov 2023 10:38:42.248 * Configuration loaded
2023-11-22 16:08:42 1:M 22 Nov 2023 10:38:42.249 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
2023-11-22 16:08:42 1:M 22 Nov 2023 10:38:42.249 * Running mode=standalone, port=6380.
2023-11-22 16:08:42 1:M 22 Nov 2023 10:38:42.259 * Server initialized
2023-11-22 16:08:42 1:M 22 Nov 2023 10:38:42.259 * Ready to accept connections tls
2023-11-22 16:16:07 1:M 22 Nov 2023 10:46:07.393 # Error accepting a client connection: error:0A000416:SSL routines::sslv3 alert certificate unknown (addr=172.17.0.1:64342 laddr=172.17.0.2:6380)
2023-11-22 16:16:09 1:M 22 Nov 2023 10:46:09.781 # Error accepting a client connection: error:0A000416:SSL routines::sslv3 alert certificate unknown (addr=172.17.0.1:64346 laddr=172.17.0.2:6380)
```

I have tried to make new certificates and some other different configs but nothing worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This sounds more appropriate for the Serverfault site as Stack Overflow is for programming questions.